# Implement an array of linked lists

Tags: c, arrays, singly-linked-list

I would like to implement an array of linked lists (in order to implement a hash table).

I have a problem at the very beginning... I defined a linked list structure, and I initialized the array of linked lists like an array of pointer to a list : `liste * Oblist[65003];` 
(Do i need to initialize it like this : `liste * Oblist[65003] = {NULL};`?)

And I want to get the list at the index 12121 (which is NULL for the moment), so I did

```
liste L = *Oblist[12121] ;
```

The program compiles without errors but when I run it I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Here is the whole code :

```
typedef struct Doublet {char * car ; struct Doublet * cdr ;}* liste ;

liste * Oblist[65003];

int main(void){

    liste L = *Oblist[32123] ;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: You seem to confuse yourself with the `typedef`ed pointer. You have an array of pointers to pointers of type `struct Doublet`.

Comment: Yep, probably, but I already used linked lists, several times, without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems. `liste` is typedef'ed as a pointer to a `struct Doublet`, so it should be

```
liste Oblist[65003];

...

liste L = Oblist[32123];
```

Or, alternatively:

```
typedef struct Doublet { ... etc. } liste;

...

liste *Oblist[65003];

...

liste *list = Oblist[32123];
```

Comment: Oh, seems like I'm a bit tired ;) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Just one little question more : if I define my array of lists like this : liste Oblist[65003]; and I make it a global variable, how should I define in the other files this variable : extern + ... ? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I suppose that it is an other stupid question and the answer is extern list Oblist[60003], no?